# How to convey a 'not-recommended' action?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, actions

A little background:

I'm making an app that allows the user to publish a listing. The catch is that before being allowed to publish, the user has to fill out a checklist of things to do before publishing the listing. The checklist includes things like 'make sure title is SEO friendly' or 'make sure correct tags are entered'. But I also want to allow the user to publish the listing without having completed the checklist. But this action is not recommended, and the user should complete the checklists whenever possible. So how do I convey that an action is allowed, but not recommended (preferably using a button) ?

Answer (score 2):

So I put together a couple of mockup buttons, but I personally don't encourage going down this route:

[image: mockup design with different publish buttons]

### Prioritizing the Call to Action

The main action of your page is to create a listing. Adding another action they have to do, especially a list with multiple actions, will only distract from the main action. Human beings love to do work with the least amount of effort. As a UX designer you have to lean into that.

But if you want posts to be properly put together, you can have the list of checklist items next to the textfield in a two column setup (I think stackoverflow does this for new users) or above the textfield, but still, it might be a distraction from the main action (creating the listing).

Another suggestion would be to create a page with all this information and then put a link to it above the textfield, or wherever. But it shouldn't distract from the main action.

### Slightly less important suggestion

Try to avoid using technical terms. The second someone needs to google something (e.g. "what is SEO"), then you've probably lost that user. Unless you have users who know/understand what search engine optimisation is. Instead, try being more specific about how they should structure their titles. Again, stackexchange's sites are a good example of this, but still titles are hard to make :D.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I like your idea. I wasn't completely clear with my background - 1. the checklist is optional and can be disabled through settings. 2. the user themselves create the checklist, so it will be unique to the user and the user will understand it since they created it.

Comment: @HiMyNameIs happy to be of assistance 1. If you want to make sure that a user has a low chance of doing anything, place it in the settings. This is why the "delete your account" button is placed deep on the settings page. 2. This is still a distraction, and the fact that they have to create it, means that users will probably ignore the feature. You can throw in chatgpt to suggest items but that can only take you so far

Answer (score 0):

The medical profession has an Against Medical Advice form that patients are required to sign if they want to check out of a hospital even though the physicians believe they should remain longer:

> Against medical advice (AMA), sometimes known as discharge against medical advice (DAMA), is a term used in health care institutions when a patient leaves a hospital against the advice of their doctor.
> While leaving before a medically specified endpoint may not promote the patient's health above their other values, there is widespread ethical and legal consensus that competent patients (or their authorized surrogates) are entitled to decline recommended treatment.
> — [Against medical advice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_medical_advice) (Wikipedia)

You could similarly offer a selection box at the end of the list to allow the user to explicitly acknowledge that:

- Some required items have not been completed.
- The site strongly discourages proceeding without having completing all items.
- The user chooses to proceed anyway, and assumes all responsibility for any negative consequences of this decision.

The wording of course would be modified to more specifically match the context of the form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I like your take on this!

Answer (score 0):

You say

> The catch is that before being allowed to publish, the user has to fill out a checklist of things to do before publishing the listing.

but do they *really* have to fill out the whole checklist before publishing the listing? Or is this what you feel they should do in order to improve their success? They'll probably have more luck finding someone interested in their listing if they do use SEO-friendly titles, but think about it. Is it really necessary to complete the task?

Do not force the user to do x tasks because you feel it will help them, especially if you do not have a clear understanding of their behavior and needs. This can hurt the user's experience and make them drop out of the process or hack around it.

- Prompt tips and guidance when the user is going to perform an action
  through progressive disclosure (Tooltips, alert containers, etc.)
  without disrupting the user's flow.
- Clearly break down the "Create Listing" process through visual
  indicators (Steps).
- Use clear and simple progress CTA's, and do not overcomplicate buttons. It's probably not necessary.

I don't have a clear understanding of the nature or maturity of your project, but as a rule of thumb if this is the first version of the publishing flow or you don't yet know your users very well, take into account the [hierarchy of needs](https://medium.theuxblog.com/design-hierarchy-of-needs-the-product-owners-guide-29ceb28205ae).

If that isn't the case and your product is very mature, or your team is pushing for a more mature feature because the scope is justified through research, try to take these checklist items and frame them as problems.

Dummy Example:

> Real estate agents who aren't tech-savvy struggle to get attention for their ads because they don't know how to make them search engine friendly, resulting in poor results.

You might be going with "Let's just show them a tooltip explaining how to write  a better title". But do the users really wanna learn about creating better titles, or do they just want their listing to do great? It could be much more valuable and easy for the user to just click a button that says "Improve my title" and provide them an SEO-friendly alternative based on their input that they can use if they choose so.

Again, pure pure speculation. But I hope my input helps on thinking through it.

**TLDR: Do not complicate the flow of your app with unnecessary requirements just because. Make them easy to complete and aid users through the journey with non-invasive prompts, adequation, and fault tolerance.**